# Monochromatic unit chord

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We know if the plane is colored by two or three colors there will always be two points of the same color and unit distance apart.I  was considering coloring the periphery of a unit circle by two colors and trying to see if it is possible to avoid a monochromatic unit chord.The problem seems elementary but I do not know whether it is already in the literature or how to settle it.ANy help/suugestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The transitive closure of the unit chord relation has equivalence classes that are vertices of regular hexagons. The vertices of each of these hexagons can be colored alternating the two colors, so you win.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you mean it is possible to avoid the said chord or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color everything from zero to, but not including, $\pi/3$, with color one; then everything from $\pi/3$ to, but not including, $2\pi/3$ with color two; color one for the next sixth of the circle, color two for the fourth sixth, then color one again, finishing with color two. Every chord of length one is bichromatic.